# Mysql Text to Date won't work

Tags: php, mysql

I got the following problem. I got a mysql field which is type "text" and there are many birthday dates in it.
I want to print the dates out and sort it in my way of date format. I can't change the type in the database because it's related to some user profile value fields.

The value's thats in the database are such this:

```
1978-12-31 23:59:59
```

This is my query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT a.value, b.username from yrt6h_community_fields_values a join yrt6h_users b on a.user_id = b.id where a.field_id = 3 order by a.value;");
```

And this my example php file:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>User:</td>
<td>Datum:</td>
</tr>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['username'] . ' : ';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row['value'];
    echo '</td></tr>';  
}
?>

</table>
```

I tried all of the date format functions of mysql, but then i got nothing.
For example I tried this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT str_to_date(a.value, '%d.%m.%Y'), ...
```

or

```
mysql_query("SELECT str_to_date(date_format(a.value, '%Y.%m.%d') %d.%m.%Y), ...
```

But I do that, the echo of the date is empty. Theres nothing to print out anymore. But why? Even if I put this query directly in the database I got NULL for the birthday value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you try to do it with `php` like -

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($yourDate));//the first paramete is the date format you want and the second is the value you are getting from database.
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more understanding, example and formats.

Comment: Just make sure that the timezone matches.

Comment: yup..that should be checked as well.

Comment: Have you tried adding h,i,s(time) in your query like (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(a.value,'%Y%m%d %h%i%s') FROM .....)

Comment: this comment should be on the question.@Nikul

Answer (score 0):

Almost there!

I would suggest that you first get the data from the db with

```
mysql_query("SELECT str_to_date(a.value, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $date = $row['date'];
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $formattedDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
}

echo $formattedDate ;
```

Does that make senese?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [PHP Date() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)?

You could do something like so: 
If you're looking for all records that match a specific date:

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //get current timestamp
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp` = '$timestamp'");
```

Or -- If you're trying to select/order by Timestamp:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `timestamp`"); //select all order by timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use mysql "cast" function.
rewrite the query in such a way:
"SELECT cast(a.value as DATETIME) new_dob,str_to_date(a.value, '%d.%m.%Y') dob from table_nm where cond"