# Compare Date with Day and Month shows false output

Tags: php, mysql

I want to compare, whether a date is bigger then the current date. With day and month!

If I only compare to month i got this output, which is correct:

> Chichiri : 08.11.2014
>   Rokno2h : 14.11.2014
>   Sasch79_AUT : 29.11.2014
>   Sonny : 08.12.2014
>   Marek : 31.12.2014
>   Fuchs : 31.12.2014
>   hauni89 : 31.12.2014
>   RIX1287 : 31.12.2014

But I want to compare to day and month, so that the first two doen't appear in the list, because their birthdays are over. But I got the following output then:

> haislpunk : 29.03.2014
>   Vastl : 19.04.2014
>   Luckypunch10 : 22.04.2014
>   DaveMetz : 25.04.2014
>   Ghoost : 24.06.2014
>   RoxoriO_AUT : 18.08.2014
>   Alchemagi : 21.08.2014
>   Shizophren83 : 29.08.2014
>   FatePhoenix : 29.09.2014
>   Testaccount : 21.10.2014
>   wernoid : 23.10.2014
>   bAc-Maus : 25.10.2014
>   Ginibal : 25.10.2014
>   CrySix1992 : 28.10.2014
>   Sasch79_AUT : 29.11.2014
>   Marek : 31.12.2014
>   Fuchs : 31.12.2014
>   hauni89 : 31.12.2014
>   RIX1287 : 31.12.2014

Here is my code with date('d.m') which doesn't work. With date ('m') is worked with month:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($test_result)){
    $curr_date = date('d.m');   
    $date = $row['value'];
    $dateFormatted = date('d.m', strtotime($date));
    //echo $dateFormatted . ' *** ' . $curr_date . '<br>';
    //wenn Geburtsmonat > aktueller Monat dann anzeigen! sonst nicht!
    if($dateFormatted >= $curr_date){
        echo $row['username'] . ' : ';
        echo date('d.m.', strtotime($date)) . date('Y');
        echo '<br />'; 

    }
}
```

I have to convert the date from database, because it is saved as a text type in the database. 
I solved this problem in this related question.
[Mysql Text to Date won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967864/mysql-text-to-date-wont-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong comparison, should compare in format `'m.d'`, **not** 'd.m' (you compare strings).

Comment: Oh my god ;) that was right and does the right thing. Thank you very much. I only changed d.m to m.d and everything works as expected!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use date object and convert the string to date format with `date_create` function.
Here is the working function for this case:

```
public  function cmpDates($date1, $date2)
    {
        $date1 = date_create($date1);
        $date2 = date_create($date2);

        $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
        return $diff;
     }
```